# Extract consecutive numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I extract in Excel consecutive (adjacent) numbers at the same row.

For example, the following data is A1, B1, C1, D1, E1.

16  20  26  27  34

How can I extract to F1 26, 27

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are we allowed to use a macro or does it have to be only worksheet functions?  I ask because CONCATENATE doesn't accept ranges so comma separating an arbitrary number of values is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this

```
=C1&", "&D1
```

Or with Office 365, you can use a new function called TextJoin.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,C1:D1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in F1

```
=IF(B1-A1=1,A1 & ",","") & IF(OR(C1-B1=1,B1-A1=1),B1 & ",","") & IF(OR(D1-C1=1,C1-B1=1),C1 & ",","") & IF(OR(E1-D1=1,D1-C1=1),D1 & ",","") & IF(OR(E1-D1=1),E1 & ",","")
```